# How to read and print the contents of a txt file in C

Tags: c, file, file-io

I am trying to find an easier way of reading a text file. I have never programed in C before so this is all new to me. My goal is to be able to run my program and have it automatically print to the screen. What I have below works but I have to enter the file in every time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char ch, file_name[25];
    FILE *fp;

       printf("Enter name of a file you wish to see\n");
       gets(file_name);

       fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); // read mode

       if (fp == NULL)
       {
          perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       printf("The contents of %s file are:\n", file_name);

       while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
          printf("%c", ch);

       fclose(fp);
       return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
Enter name of a file you wish to see
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
Data.txt
The contents of Data.txt file are:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Aside: `char ch` should be `int ch` as returned by function `fgetc()`.

Comment: If you want to open the *same* file every time, use `char file_name[] = "Data.txt";`

Comment: What are you learning from that says to use `gets()`?

Comment: ...especially with such a small buffer `file_name[25];`

Comment: @JohnFore I have updated your accepted answer for completeness and posterity. Perhaps investigating the different options will help you understand the many ways C allows you to approach solving a problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few ways to define the filename without user intervention. In all cases, remove

```c
printf("Enter name of a file you wish to see\n");
gets(file_name);
```

---

Replace `gets(file_name);` with `strcpy(file_name, "Data.txt");`.

You will need to also `#include <string.h>`.

---

Replace `file_name[25]` with `file_name[] = "Data.txt"`

---

Replace `char ch, file_name[25];` with `char ch; char *file_name = "Data.txt";`
You could also declare the string as constant: `const char *file_name = "Data.txt";`.

---

Replace `gets(file_name);` with `snprintf(file_name, (sizeof(file_name)/sizeof(file_name[0]))-1, "Data.txt");`

`sizeof(file_name)/sizeof(file_name[0])` calculates the maximum length of the array by dividing the total array's size by the length of a single element. We subtract 1 to reserve an element for the string termination character `'\0'`.

`snprintf()` would allow you to build the filename programmatically.

---

Remove `, file_name[25]`.

Replace `fp = fopen(file_name, "r");` with `fp = fopen("Data.txt", "r");`.

Replace `printf("The contents of %s file are:\n", file_name);` with `printf("The contents of the file are:\n");`

(Note the loss of functionality)

Comment: Why not just `char* file_name = "Data.txt";` ?

Comment: Removing `gets()` prevents it from being overwritten. Why not `const char`? Why not `snprintf()`? How long is a piece of string!?

Answer (score 3):

Will you always be reading from Data.txt ? If so you can hardcode the file name and replace `gets(file_name);` with `char * file_name = "Data.txt"` . If you do this also remove the current definition of `file_name` to avoid a redefinition error.